# Fetching individual column values despite GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**Background**

I have some table for sports data. I have a `team` table, and a `manager` table.

A row in the `manager` table has a `team_id`.

I want to present teams that have more than one manager, and currently the output is the following:

```
| Team  | Managers |
| TEAM1 | 2        |
| TEAM2 | 4        |
```

(This is a very simplified version, but you get the gist, I think.)

I fetch this data with a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Managers,
    team.name as Team
FROM team
    LEFT JOIN manager ON manager.team_id = team.id
GROUP BY team.id HAVING Managers > 1;
```

**Upgrade**

I'm being asked to add another output to this, namely the name of all managers for these teams, that have more than one.

Desired example output:

```
| Team  | Managers | Names                              |
| TEAM1 | 2        | Al Bal, Cal Dal                    |
| TEAM2 | 4        | Fal Gal, Hal Jal, Kal Lal, Mal Nal |
```

**Question**

How can I fetch info from all individual rows, while grouping them like this?

Alternatively, is there a way to get the desired concatenation of manager names, while still having them grouped like shown?

So far, if I just add `manager.name` to the list of things to `SELECT`, it just outputs one of them. Not that I was expecting it to work. Just throwing it in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to concatenate the different manager names on one row.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS Managers,
    team.name as Team,
    GROUP_CONCAT(manager.name ORDER BY manager.name)    
FROM team
    LEFT JOIN manager ON manager.team_id = team.id
GROUP BY team.id HAVING Managers > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `group_concat()` to get the names.  However, you should also fix the joins:

```
SELECT t.name as Team, COUNT(*) as num_managers,
       GROUP_CONCAT(m.name SEPARATOR ' ') as managers
FROM team t JOIN
     manager m
     ON m.team_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING num_managers > 1;
```

Because you need a match to get managers, an outer join is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
select team.team_name,count(*) as managers,
        group_concat(m_name separator ',') as managers_names 
    from team left join manager on manager.team_id=team.team_id 
    group by team.team_id having managers > 1;
```